# How to charge lipo with a laboratory power supply?

Tags: power-supply, lipo, charge

I've bought a good laboratory power supply (0...30V and 0...5A).
I'd like to charge my 3S Lipo Battery Pack with it.

How to do this?

Comment: Buy a 3S Lipo charger module and plug it in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A direct way of doing it is to first analyze the battery and find its C rating. Then set the current limit of the power supply to under C/10, to be safe. So for say 2600 mAh battery, the limit should be under 260 mA.

Next step is to get the charged voltage of the battery. For lithium batteries, that's 4,2 V per cell. You have a 3 S battery, so 3 cells in series, giving you 12,6 V. Set the voltage on the power supply to that value. Check it at the output with a good voltmeter, if you have one, just to be safe, since LiPo batteries don't like over-voltages.

Next step is to connect the battery to the power supply with an amperemeter connected in series in series. If your power supply already has an ampmeter, then you can use that.

You need to watch the meter and wait for the current indicated on it to drop down to zero. When it's zero, the battery is fully charged.

Do keep in mind that some LiPo batteries have special connectors for balancing cells. If your does have that, it would be a good idea to use a charger that can make use of that connector.

Comment: I would charge the cells one at a time to the same final voltage so that a weak cell is not driven over voltage or use a cell balancing charger.  The risk of fire is real.

Comment: @KalleMP  Yes, but that depends on the assembly of the cells. If they're all wired in series and have no parallel connection, it can be difficult to charge then cell by cell. I thought that such an arrangement is simply stupid, but I have seen products that use lithium cells, draw quite a bit of current and are wired in such manner.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this relation

> P=IV

By passive sign convention , I is the current that enters the positive terminal of the component or enters the side which is at higher potential than the other.

Connect positive terminal of your battery with positive terminal of your supply and do the same with negative terminals. Set the voltage of the source to be of same value as the battery rated voltage (If battery is 12V , set the source to be 12V) and current to be below the limit , which is **x/10 A** , where **x** is your **total battery charge**.Higher current  will result in lesser charging time but may damage your battery.Use ammeter to measure the current flowing in the circuit which would come out be zero when battery is fully charged.

The power relation comes out to be positive  (when applied on Battery) which indicates that power is being stored inside the battery and power relation is negative for source which indicates that power is being supplied.

About the capacitors and other regulated components ,they already exist inside your supply.

Also Lipo , may explode if you are not handling it safely so look for other professional answers on this forum before proceeding.

Best option is to buy a lipo battery charger which has charge indicator and much other features.
`